# how to create and suggestionbox (textbox) using c#

Tags: c#, autosuggest

i want to create a suggestion box like in google. I want the data from database in suggestion box and i have created a dataset .
i looked through all the properties of textbox and set `AutoCompleteMode=SuggestAppend` , `AutoCompleteSource=CustomSource` , and gave few values at `AutoCompleteCustomSource (collection)`
and it actually worked. What should i do to do the same using data from database?

Answer (score 3):

take out the data from your `db table`, prepare a `Collection` and bind it to your controls `AutoCompleteCustomSource` through code.

see the code  below:

```
public void BindAutoCompleteList(DataTable myDataTable)
{
     AutoCompleteStringCollection acDataSource= new  
     AutoCompleteStringCollection();
     foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
      {
         acDataSource.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
      }


     txtBoxAuto.Clear(); 
     txtBoxAuto.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
     txtBoxAuto.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
     txtBoxAuto.AutoCompleteCustomSource = acDataSource;
}
```

and call this `BindAutoCompleteList()` in the Form's constructor or  any location suitable to your app.

where `myDataTable` consists of your db table rows